Declaration is incompatible with "HALL_Obj hall_M1"
I need to write the code explained in this comment in a Texas Instruments project (with Code Composer Studio):
//this is in motor1_drive.c:
// Enable MOTOR1_HALL_CAL pre-defined symbols, run the motor with FAST for angle calibration
// Copy hall_M1.thetaCalBuf[] to hallAngleBuf[]
// 1->1, 2->2, 3->3, 4->4, 5->5, 6->6, 6->0
// Disable MOTOR1_HALL_CAL pre-defined symbols after calibration for normal operation
                                    // 6           1              2
                                    // 3           4              5
                                    // 6

//I've tried this but an error (one for every line below) exist:
//**declaration is incompatible with "const float32_t hallAngleBuf[7]"**
const float32_t hallAngleBuf[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0 };
hallAngleBuf[0] = hall_M1.thetaCalBuff[0]; //I've tried only the first element copy


Consider that:
//this is in hall.h:
typedef struct _HALL_Obj_
{
    float32_t speedSwitch_Hz;      // Hz
    uint32_t  timeStampCAP;        //
    float32_t thetaBuff[7];         // 1~6 are valid value
    float32_t thetaHall_rad;        //
    float32_t thetaDelta_rad;       //
    float32_t thetaHall_pu;         //
#ifdef HALL_CAL
    float32_t thetaCalBuff[7];               //
#endif  //HALL_CAL
} HALL_Obj;


The pre-defined symbols I have already enabled/disabled them, it is done from the project properties
------------------------1° EDIT WITH YOUR SOLUTIONS---------------------------
float32_t hallAngleBuf[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0 } //line 194
hallAngleBuf[0] = hall_M1.thetaCalBuff[0];           //line 196

ERROR LOG:
>> Compilation failure
src_control/subdir_rules.mk:9: recipe for target 'src_control/motor1_drive.obj' failed
"../src_control/motor1_drive.c", line 196: warning #78-D: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier
"../src_control/motor1_drive.c", line 196: error #148: declaration is incompatible with "float32_t hallAngleBuf[7]" (declared at line 194)
"../src_control/motor1_drive.c", line 196: error #150: variable "hallAngleBuf" has already been initialized
"../src_control/motor1_drive.c", line 196: error #28: expression must have a constant value
"../src_control/motor1_drive.c", line 223: fatal error #35: #error directive: Not a right hall angle buffer for this project, need to do hall calibration
3 errors and 1 catastrophic error detected in the compilation of "../src_control/motor1_drive.c".
Compilation terminated.
gmake: *** [src_control/motor1_drive.obj] Error 1
gmake: Target 'all' not remade because of errors.

**** Build Finished ****

DO NOT consider the "fatal error #35: #error directive.." ! it is for a define that has nothing to do with the code in question, it is inherent to the fact that I have to do recalibration of Hall sensor (which is precisely with the code we are trying to solve here in this post)


Please [edit] and show the verbatim error log.

I suppose there is a variable hallAngleBuf declared somewhere else in motor1_drive.c. Or maybe in a file included in motor1_drive.c, which would be a bad idea anyway. The warning this declaration has no storage class or type specifier is also quite strange. You should show more code around line 194 and 196.

In the project I can assure you that it is not initialized anywhere else hallAngleBuf because I did a global search and nothing was found. The motor1_drive.c file can be found here: https://file.io/MbbzWbb1rqyS

Without seeing more, I can't help any further. My hint would be remove progressively stuff from motor1_drive.c until it compiles and find out what triggers the problem.

motor1_drive.c is autogenerated by the IDE .. the only code I added are what I shown in the amin post ..

motor1_drive.c is autogenerated  (!?) I thought that was your code. I don't get it. And the original version (the one with const) is blatantly wrong, how could this have been autogenerated....(?!)

the only code I added are two lines const float32_t hallAngleBuf[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0 }; and hallAngleBuf[0] = hall_M1.thetaCalBuff[0];

in fact if I remove them, there are no errors and the compilation is correct

I'm sorry if I misspoke. I repeat. the autogenerated code does not contain const float32_t hallAngleBuf[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0 } and hallAngleBuf[0] = hall_M1.thetaCalBuff[0] ... these two I added to try to do what is described to me in the comment (autogenerated) in the main post code

in any case, if you need more project files I can upload them. Unfortunately, this problem is serious and we are unable to move the project forward. However, I remain available

This is probably too big a problem for stackoverflow. I'll give up here. Good luck.

This declares a const array:
const float32_t hallAngleBuf[7] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0 };

therefore you cannot assign values to it like in:
hallAngleBuf[0] = hall_M1.thetaCalBuff[0];

Remove the const and it should work.
This compiles.

As far as I understood you want to copy the 7 elements, so you probably want this:
// copy hall_M1.thetaCalBuff to hallAngleBuf
memcpy(hallAngleBuf, hall_M1.thetaCalBuff, sizeof(hallAngleBuf[0]) * 7);

sizeof(hallAngleBuf[0]) is equivalent to sizeof(float32_t).

thanks for the response, I still have errors. I edited the main poste

@KaleM you need to post more information. Post the verbatim error log.

where do i find this file in the compiler? I am using code composer studio

is it perhaps the log that is in the "console" section during compilation? (and that indicates the errors). If so, do I copy paste or upload the file? (which I don't know where it is)

Copy the error log from the console of whatever. And paste it into the question. The error log is just text

Done. Tell me if it's okay. Thank you

I think you should not consider the "fatal error #35: #error directive.." it is due to the fact that I have to do recalibration of Hall sensor (which is precisely done with the code we are trying to write here in this post)
